# Can create report of 2 events in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

This is my event:

```
 gtag('event', 'KeyWords', {
            'Category': ctg,         
            'Keyword': keyword 
         });
```

Curent it create 2 sub items in Keywords: Category and Keyword

[image]

Can create report with Keyword is a sub item of Category?

```
Ex: Keywords -> Category -> Keyword
```

I want to compile Keyword statistics for each Category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a report in Explorer that looks at both of those.

You just need toake sure you are passing the parameters as custom dimensions in your admin panel.

In Explorer, select your two custom dimensions. For your metrics, decide whether you want to see the total number of events or users and add that to the metrics section.

Then, it is as easy as dropping them into the report in the correct places and adjusting your timeframe.